# printing token in grammar in bison(yacc)

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I'm having trouble using the tokens in my code in bison
I defined the tokens by:

```
#define YYSTYPE struct node*

typedef struct node{
char* token;
node* left;
node* right;
}node;
```

and for part of my grammar is:

```
%token STRING CHARVAL VOID



s: code
code: rettype name ;
rettype: VOID 
name: STRING|CHARVAL;
```

is it possible to do something like :

```
rettype: VOID {printf("%s",$1->token);}
```

or

```
rettype: VOID {$$ = $1;}
```

part of the code i'm test is just:

```
void foo
```

that's for now my main problem...
when i'm trying this i get this error: `Segmentation fault(core dumped)`
i tried to find an explanation or a solution everywhere but didn't find any or didn't understood them enough, could someone direct me to the solution of this please?

Comment: Most likely, your lexer is not setting `yylval` properly before it returns a token.  But you don't show your lexer code.

Answer (score 0):

Bison is dependent on the lexer properly setting the `yylval` global variable with any token type information as part of the tokens it feeds to bison.  If you are using flex, you probably need/want something like:

```
"void"    { yylval.token = "void";
            yylval.left = yylval.right = 0;
            return VOID }
[a-z]*    { yylval.token = strdup(yytext);
            yylval.left = yylval.right = 0;
            return STRING; }
```

It is important to set *every field* of yylval to something reasonable, that will persist through subsequent calls to yylex (thus the call to strdup rather than using yytext directly, as yytext will change).

Comment: i tried what you suggested, gives an error: `invalid use of undefined type struct node `

Comment: You need to include your definition of struct node in a header file you include in your lexer.

Comment: the struct node is defined in the yacc file and if i try to define it in the lex file, the segmentation error comes right at the start